# How to use groupby to add values to empty columns using pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

have a df with values :

df1

```
a         b        
tom
luke         
mark     132
mark
luke     123
tom
luke
tom      145
```

how to add `b` values to the rest of empty other names like this

expected output:

```
a         b        
tom      145
luke     123      
mark     132
mark     132
luke     123
tom      145
luke     123
tom      145
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['b'] = df.sort_values('b').groupby('a').ffill()
```

Or fill with `mean` if your data is numerical:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('mean'))
```

Output:

```
      a      b
0   tom  145.0
1  luke  123.0
2  mark  132.0
3  mark  132.0
4  luke  123.0
5   tom  145.0
6  luke  123.0
7   tom  145.0
```